# Connecting AC wires to aluminium PCB

Tags: pcb-assembly

How do I connect AC wires to the aluminium PCB pads? Is it safe for user?

Comment: I am worry about High voltage on PCB because distance of copper and aluminium is very low (around 100 um)

Comment: Please explain further (click edit on your post). The dielectric used in the aluminum-clad board process will mostly define the isolation between the traces and the aluminum. I know some well-certified products use 120 or 240VAC directly onto an aluminum-clad board for LED applications.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminium PCB are made with aluminium **core** (instead of FR-4 or similar). But the circuit tracks and pads are still made with copper:

[image]

The pads can therefore be soldered the usual way (you may need a powerful iron, though, because the heat gets disipated quickly due to the aluminium base).

It does not make any difference regarding safety either.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to use a connector.  You can connect the header pins to whichever tracks or polygons or core on whichever layer you need for your PCB.  The connector will be the safest option for the user because they can plug/unplug it at will in a safe and controlled manner, enhances serviceability and the energized parts will be protected and concealed from the user standpoint.